# CSS Unexpected border around login form fields

Tags: html, css

I want to create a drop down login form for my website and I have found a great tutorial on the web.. Everything is prefect except I got a unexpected border around the login form fields and login button.. Please see the image for better understanding..

[image]

**(Edited)** Sorry I forgot to add the HTML Code..

**HTML**

```
 <div id="pageTop">
    <div id="pageTopWrap">
      <div id="pageTopLogo">
      <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="UmtBook" title="UmtBook V1.0"></a>
      </div>
     <div id="pageTopRest">
       <div id="menu1">
       <nav>
           <ul>
             <li id="login">
           <a id="login-trigger" href="#">Log In<span>▼</span>
           </a>
           <div id="login-content">
                <form>
                    <fieldset id="inputs">
                        <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>   
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="actions">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>         
         </li>
         </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
         <div id="menu2">
           <div id="set">
              <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" title="Umt Book V1.0"></a>
              <a href="#">Menu_item_1</a>
              <a href="#">Menu_item_2</a>
             </div>
           </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the **CSS** Code.

```
nav ul {
  margin: 5;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;  
  width:100px;  
}

nav li {
  float: left;          
}

nav #login {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;  
}

nav #login-trigger,
nav #signup a {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; 
}

nav #signup a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

nav #login-trigger {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

nav #login-trigger:hover,
nav #login .active,
nav #signup a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

nav #login-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;    
  background: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#eee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);  
  padding: 35px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  width:100px;
}

nav li #login-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 270px;
  height:120px;  
}

/*--------------------*/

#inputs input {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 238px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
}

#inputs input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e8c291;
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
}

/*--------------------*/

#login #actions {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#login #submit {        
  background-color: #d14545;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e97171), to(#d14545));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;    
  border: 1px solid #7e1515;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}

#login #submit:hover,
#login #submit:focus {      
  background-color: #e97171;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d14545), to(#e97171));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
}   

#login #submit:active {     
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;       
}

#login #submit::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}

#login label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#login label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

Can anybody please see the code and point out the error... Please help me.. Thanks in Advance....

Comment: You'll have to provide some HTML markup for us ....

Comment: without just sharing the CSS very hard to understand what your  HTML structure.

Comment: Yes.. I have provided the HTML code now.. Please have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css Class

```
#inputs {
border-width: 0px;
}
```